# Making a custom JPA Hibernate sequence for non id field

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entity, field, sequence

**I have this entity.**

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "public")
public class Policeman implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;



    @Column
    private String number;


    @Column
    private String fam;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String otch;
//setters, getters i ommited
}
```

I would like to make a custom autogeneration for field "number" for non "id" field when record inserts in db. I want to make an autoincrement. I want to use the following pattern "policeman-" + several zeros + number. policeman - (number consists 4 digits, empty ones fills with zeros).

**For example, generated numbers such as**

policeman-0001

the next one is:

policeman-0002

another example:

policeman-0315

etc.

Which technologies, libraries, methods, annotations should i use to implement this? Thanks